# Disabling viewing source codes in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, security

I just disabled the inspect feature in chrome on my website. And I also did `onmousedown='return true;' onselectstart='return false;'` to copy and paste my content in other places.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});</script>
```

this code is for disabling the inspect feature in chrome. I want to know does this effect to the SEO of my website in google searching or not?

Comment: It does not disabling the inspect feature in chrome. Just the context menu. You can still access it via the Chrome menu or keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: People who want to copy your content, *will* copy your content. Your approach is simply harming UX in the web. Also using inline-scripts is anything but secure.

Comment: Short answer you can't. A copy is on the users computer and they may do with it what they want. Don't show the page if you don't want people to see it.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is - don't do this. It doesn't work.  If you don't want a user to be able to view your code, modify the architecture to run proprietary operations on the server side.